# ansible shell command syntax error in using colon

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

Team,

I have a task finding mounts and counting them if they are 0 or greater than 64 in count.

I tried double quoting colon and also single quote whole command but no luck. Can anyone hint how to resolve this?

```
      - name: "Mounts count on GPU Nodes should not be 64+"
        shell: 'mount | grep -Ec '/dev/sd.*\<csi' | awk '{ print $0,"mounts found on hostname"($0>64? " that are more than 64." : ".") }''
        register: mounts_count
        changed_when: false
        failed_when:
        delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
        with_items: "{{ groups['kube-gpu-node'] }}"

      - name: Check if csi related mounts are present on gpu nodes
        assert:
          that:
            - item.stdout is search('0')
          fail_msg: " mounts are present on this node"
          success_msg: "mounts are not present on this node"
        loop: "{{ mounts_count.results }}"
        loop_control:
          label: "{{ item.item }}"
        ignore_errors: yes
```

output:

```
   ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
     expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'


   The offending line appears to be:

         - name: "Mounts count on GPU Nodes should not be 64+"
           shell: 'mount | grep -Ec '/dev/sd.*\<csi' | awk '{ print $0,"mounts found on hostname"($0>64? " that are more than 64." : ".") }''
                                     ^ here
   This one looks easy to fix. It seems that there is a value started
   with a quote, and the YAML parser is expecting to see the line ended
   with the same kind of quote. For instance:

       when: "ok" in result.stdout

   Could be written as:

      when: '"ok" in result.stdout'

   Or equivalently:

      when: "'ok' in result.stdout"
   We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
   unbalanced quotes. If starting a value with a quote, make sure the
   line ends with the same set of quotes. For instance this arbitrary
   example:

       foo: "bad" "wolf"

   Could be written as:

       foo: '"bad" "wolf"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by espacing <  and double quotes inside expression and double quoting whole command

```
shell: "mount | grep -Ec '/dev/sd.*\\<csi' | awk '{ print $0,\"mounts found on hostname\"($0>64? \" that are more than 64.\" : \".\") }'"
```